# How to auto generate a deployment version, according to the underlaying installed software under this specific deployment?

Tags: deployment, version, remote-server

Our team currently deploys various packages, software, and even operating systems remotely. We require an automated process to generate a version for each deployment, enabling us to keep track of exactly what was deployed using that specific deployment version.
Is there a common way to auto-generate this deployment version?
F(bunch of software versions) = deployment version => what is F?